# How do I refresh GT5 every X amount of seconds?

Tags: command-line, scripts, files, pipe, du

I'm using the [terminal GUI program GT5](http://gt5.sourceforge.net), which is a "du -browser". I want to have this program either automatically refresh every 30 seconds, or run every 30 seconds, quit, then repeat. What is the best way to do this? I haven't been able to find anything, mainly because all the GT5 google results have to do with the game and not the (poorly-named) linux app.

Answer (score 0):

Easy peasy:

```
watch -n30 -t 'gt5'
```

This command runs `gt5` every 30 seconds.

Comment: There's no output though....

Comment: @Programmer4Life try now